# Amazon Lex slot won't save value in it. Returns empty

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I am trying to implement a check that gives the user an option to update the value of a specific slot within an intent after user **Denies** at *confirmIntent* step.

I have a **newUser** intent that has the following slots:

[image: Slots defined in intent]

The **updateNewUser** is a custom slot type (expand values) with following entries:

[image]

Now, when a user **Denies** at confirmIntent step, I ask the user the slot which he/she wants to update/change, and store the user input value in **updateNewUser** slot using Lambda function elicitSlot. But here comes the problem.

- Bot plays confirmation prompt with all captured values
- User says "No" at confirmIntent
- Bot elicits the **updateNewUser** slot by asking "What value do you
  want to update?"
- If user says a word that is an exact match of the entries of
  **updateNewUser** custom slot type, then it works fine
- If user says a similar (not exact match) word, like "name" or "email"
  or "number", no value is stored inside **updateNewUser** and the bot
  continues to confimation prompt.

Following is my Lambda code:

```
def newUser(intent_request):

slot_details = intent_request['currentIntent']['slotDetails']
slots = intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']
f_name = slots['f_name']
l_name = slots['l_name']
cellNum = slots['cellNum']
emailAdd = slots['emailAdd']
updateSlot = slots['updateNewUser']
session_attributes = intent_request['sessionAttributes'] if intent_request['sessionAttributes'] is not None else {}
confirmation_status = intent_request['currentIntent']['confirmationStatus']


if intent_request['invocationSource'] == 'DialogCodeHook':
    validation_result = validate_newusr(intent_request['currentIntent']['slots'], intent_request['currentIntent']['slotDetails'])
    if not validation_result['isValid']:
        slots = intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']
        slots[validation_result['violatedSlot']] = None
        slots['updateNewUser'] = None
        return elicit_slot(
            session_attributes,
            intent_request['currentIntent']['name'],
            slots,
            validation_result['violatedSlot'],
            validation_result['message']
        )
    
    if confirmation_status == 'Denied':
        slots = intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']
        
        return elicit_slot(
            session_attributes,
            intent_request['currentIntent']['name'],
            slots,
            'updateNewUser',
            {
                'contentType': 'SSML',
                'content': '<speak>Which value do you want to change?</speak>'
            }
        )
    
    
    return delegate(
        session_attributes,
        intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']
    )
    
return close(
        session_attributes,
        'Fulfilled',
        {
            'contentType': 'SSML',
            'content': '<speak>Your account has been created, and you will shortly receive an email to set up your password. Now, would you like to make a reservation for yourself, or for somone else?</speak>'
        }
    )
```

And following is the validation code:

```
def validate_newusr(slots, slot_details):

f_name = slots['f_name']
l_name = slots['l_name']
cellNum = slots['cellNum']
emailAdd = slots['emailAdd']
updateSlot = slots['updateNewUser']


if f_name:
    if ' ' in f_name:
        f_name = f_name.replace(' ', '')
        slots['f_name'] = f_name
            
if l_name:
    if ' ' in l_name:
        l_name = l_name.replace(' ', '')
        slots['l_name'] = l_name

if cellNum and (len(cellNum) != 10):
    return build_validation_result(
        False,
        'cellNum',
        '<speak>Please provide a valid, 10 digit phone number.</speak>'
    )
    
    
return build_validation_result(     #I use this to check whether updateNewUser stores something or not. But of course I only paste this code here at confirmIntent step; not before.
            False,
            'updateNewUser',
            str(updateSlot)
        )


    
if updateSlot:                      # this code won't run because updateSlot is empty
    
    return build_validation_result(     
            False,
            'updateNewUser',
            str(updateSlot)
        )
    
    if len(slot_details['updateNewUser']['resolutions']) == 1 and str(list(slot_details['updateNewUser']['resolutions'][0].values())[0]).lower() in ['last name','first name', 'cell phone number', 'email address']:
        slots['updateNewUser'] = list(slot_details['updateNewUser']['resolutions'][0].values())[0]
    
    if len(slot_details['updateNewUser']['resolutions']) == 0 or str(list(slot_details['updateNewUser']['resolutions'][0].values())[0]).lower() not in ['last name','first name', 'cell phone number', 'email address']:
        return build_validation_result(
            False,
            'updateNewUser',
            '<speak>Sorry, I could not understand. Please say first name, last name, phone number, or email address.</speak>'
        )
        
    if slots['updateNewUser'] == 'first name':
        return build_validation_result(
            False,
            'f_name',
            '<speak>Please say your updated first name.</speak>'
        )
        
    if slots['updateNewUser'] == 'last name':
        return build_validation_result(
            False,
            'l_name',
            '<speak>Please say your updated last name.</speak>'
        )
        
    if slots['updateNewUser'] == 'cell phone number':
        return build_validation_result(
            False,
            'cellNum',
            '<speak>Please say, or type your updated phone number.</speak>'
        )
        
    if slots['updateNewUser'] == 'email address':
        return build_validation_result(
            False,
            'emailAdd',
            '<speak>Please say your updated email address.</speak>'
        )
        
return {'isValid': True}
```

Here are some screenshots of the chat:

1. User declines at confirmIntent, bot asks which value to update:

[image]

2. User says "name", bot jumps to confirmation prompt

[image]

3. If exact matching word is provided to Lex, it accepts it:

[image]

4. Returning what value bot stored in updateNewUser in case of "name" as input:

[image]

5. Another example:

[image]

It only accepts exact match in my case. But if I make **updateNewUser** slot as mandatory/required, it starts to accept similar words too and works fine. But I need this slot as optional. My goal is to update a single slot instead of repeating the whole intent. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I would suggest changing the resolution of the `updateNewUser` slot type to restricted values and synonyms. That will enable you to add synonyms that match with your base value.

Ensure that your `valueSelectionStrategy` is `TOP_RESOLUTION` so that you get the base value rather than the user's raw input.

This simplifies your lambda as you would only need to cater for a single value per line.

[Custom Slot Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/howitworks-custom-slots.html)